# How to properly structure <xsl:if>?

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

I'm having trouble calling  on a value
Lets say I have xml structure:

```
<1><2><3>jjj</1></2></3>
```

how to use that `jjj` value into `<xsl:if>` ?

I have tried

```
<xsl:if value="jjj">
    <newValue>kkk</newValue>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `<xsl:if>` is `<xsl:if test="someValue">`. Your template, as per the sample XML should look like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="1/2/3 = 'jjj'">
        <newValue>kkk</newValue>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And by the way, **element names in XML cannot start with numbers**.